# How to iterate over list values in dictionary per key?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, while-loop

Here's my code:

```
msgs = {}
msgs['ch1']=['testmsg1', 'testmsg2']
msgs['ch2']=['testmsg3','testmsg4','testmsg5']

counter = 0
for key, val in msgs.items():
    while counter < len(val):
        print(key, val[counter])
        counter += 1
```

Here's the output I'm currently getting:

```
ch1 testmsg1
ch1 testmsg2
ch2 testmsg5
```

And here's the output I'd like:

```
ch1 testmsg1
ch1 testmsg2
ch2 testmsg3
ch2 testmsg4
ch2 testmsg5
```

Thanks in advance for your help, I'm still learning and would benefit from an explanation!

Comment: You just need to reset your `counter` the line before the `while` loop (inside the for loop). `counter = 0` and rerun. That being said, why not just iterate the list with `for msg in val: print(key, msg)` instead of monkeying with a while loop and counter?

Comment: Or drop the counter and the while loop and loop with `for value in val: print(key, value)`. There's no need to overcomplicate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to get all the values in the list. As @Jnevill said, you could fix how you're using the counter, but since you know how many objects are in the list you would be better to use a [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) instead of a while loop. So

```
msgs = {}
msgs['ch1']=['testmsg1', 'testmsg2']
msgs['ch2']=['testmsg3','testmsg4','testmsg5']

for key, val in msgs.items():
    for element in val:
        print(key, element)
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was overcomplicating it. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the while loop here, you need to move your counter variable inside the for loop like such:

```
msgs = {}
msgs['ch1']=['testmsg1', 'testmsg2']
msgs['ch2']=['testmsg3','testmsg4','testmsg5']

for key, val in msgs.items():
    counter = 0
    while counter < len(val):
        print(key, val[counter])
        counter += 1
```

This way, your counter will reset to 0 when it goes to the next key in the dictionary. Previously, the counter is 0 at `testmsg1`, 1 at `testmsg2`, but when it encounters the key `ch2`, the counter is now at 2, and only prints `testmsg5`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the following, or am I missing something?

```
msgs = {}
msgs['ch1']=['testmsg1', 'testmsg2']
msgs['ch2']=['testmsg3','testmsg4','testmsg5']

for key in msgs:
    for val in msgs[key]:
        print(key, val)
```

Comment: The original approach with `msgs.items()` was better because you don't need the index access with `msgs[key]` afterwards.

Comment: @Matthias I had to look that up, did not realize .items() is apparently much faster.

Answer (score 0):

In a single iteration:

- make a string template
- use `map` to apply the template to each value in the list
- use `print` with separator `\n`

```
for k, vs in msgs.items():
    template = k + ' {}'
    print(*map(template.format, vs), sep='\n')
```

Or with a simple 2-lines way using `str.join`:

```
for k, vs in msgs.items():
    print('\n'.join(f'{k} {v}' for v in vs))
```